# How to set vim key mapping to normal?

Tags: vim, terminal

I know "normal" is a subjective term, but you know what I mean.  I'm on a mac.  I want "delete" to backspace, hitting left at the beginning of a line jumps to end of previous line,  and all the other keys I'm used to.  Like I'm typing right now.  Is there a simple way to do this and still be able to use the Terminal non-gui version without having to actually remap each key individually?  please no "get used to it" answers.  I just need it for one class.  Don't want to get used to it. :)  The terminal type (or whatever you call it) is xterm-256color/tcsh.

Comment: Maybe try `:help MakeMacWorkLikeLinux`? Seriously though, you're going to need to remap some keys individually.

Comment: What if you have several lines to join together? Use shift-j in normal mode. (This is the reason I use Vim at the very beginning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at vim's easy mode - simply start vim with the `-y` flag(or just run `evim`) to make it behave like a regular text editor.

When in easy mode, you are always in insert mode. If you ever need regular vim commands, use `CTRL-L` to enter vim's normal mode, or `CTRL-O` to enter a single normal mode command and then return to insert mode.

More info in `:help easy` and `:help evim-keys`.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the delete key, start with

```
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

The same thing can be accomplished with

```
:set bs=2
```

See `:help bs` for full details.

As a last resort, you may try

```
:fixdel
" see :help fixdel
```

Comment: `:help bs` should aid in writing papers too, right? Or maybe political speeches?